# Entropy of a Binary Sequence with Restrictions

Tags: probability, random-variables, information-theory, entropy

Consider a length-L binary sequence $e_{1:L}$ of i.i.d. symbols, where a symbol can be $1$ with probability $p_{f}$ and $0$ with probability $1-p_{f}$. The entropy associated with such a sequence can be easily found to be:
\begin{equation}
H(e_{1:L}) = LH_{2}(p_{f})
\end{equation}
where $H_{2}(.)$ is the binary entropy function.

Consider if we now make $i$ particular length-L sequences impossible (e.g. '$000001$', '$001001$' and '$010101$' have probability $0$ if we take $i=3$ with $L = 6$), what would the new value of the entropy $H(e_{1:L})$ be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit - my previous answer wrongly assumed a fair coin.

The question is practically unanswerable, because the entropy would depend not only on $i$ (how many messages are supressed) but on which are - and even then the entropy should be computed by brute force calculation.

An approximation for large $L$:

For large $L$, the AEP property says that "most" sequences ("most" in the probability sense), are inside the typical set $A_e^L$, with size $2^{L H_r}$ (where $H_r = h(p_f)$).

If we reduce this typical set by deleting a fraction of $0<\alpha<1$ sequences (uniformly) from it, then entropy rate  becomes
$$ H'_r= \frac1L \log(2^{L H_r}- \alpha 2^{L H_r})= h(p_f) +\frac1L \log(1-\alpha) \approx h(p_f) - \log(e) \frac{\alpha}{L} \tag1  $$

where the last approximation assumes  $\alpha \ll 1$ (logs are in base two).

Depending on the scenario, it might be reasonable to asssume that the $i$ suppresed messages are taken from the typical set, so that $i=\alpha 2^{L H_r} $ or $\alpha = i \, 2^{-L h(p_f)}$ .

Alternatively, we may prefer to assume that the $i$ suppresed message are taken uniformly  from the total set, so that  $i = \alpha 2^{L }$ , and then $\alpha = i \, 2^{-L} $

Comment: The issue is that the remaining sequences still have probabilities which depend on the probability $p_{f}$. This question derives from trying to find the entropy $H(X_{1:L}|Y_{1:L})$ of an $L$-long input sequence $X_{1:L}$ to a BSC with cross-over probability $p_{f}$ where we know the output sequence $Y_{1:L}$. However, to complicate matters we also know that the input sequence has some impossible sequences.

Comment: @SamuelLiebana Silly me, I assumed a fair coin. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am now working through your answer. May I ask you to clarify what $n$ is?

Comment: $n$ is just $L$ (not my day...) Fixed :-)

Comment: May I ask one more question: if the suppressed sequences come from the total set does the expression for the entropy rate remain the same?

Answer (score 1):

With such restrictions, the digits of the sequence are no longer i.i.d. For example, while looking at 6-long binary sequences and restrict the all zeros string, after observing “00000”, the sixth string is deterministic. So, the entropy of the string can no longer be written as only a function of the marginal distribution of the digits. To find this entropy, you need to treat  $e_{1:L}$ as a single random variable and find the entropy by plugging in this new joint probability $p(e_1,e_2,...,e_L)$ that describes the restrictions into the definition of entropy.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand that the sequence would no longer be i.i.d and was looking for an expression for this entropy. Maybe in terms of the original 'unrestricted entropy' or using a decomposition of the entropy. I am also aware that the expression would be a function of the weight of the restricted sequences.

Comment: You can’t find a general expression that only depend on $L, i$. You can only find it for a fixed set of restricted strings because the things you can restrict aren’t equiprobable, so it matters what strings are restricted. Secondly, by simply saying their probability is shifted to zero, you aren’t fully defining what the new joint probability is. If the all zeros string is restricted, how is the $(1-p_f)^L$ density redistributed? In the end, you won’t be able to find an expression that is both useful and general enough. You might as well just plug in the new joint probability

Comment: Ok, great. What would the expression for the new joint probability then look like? This will surely also depend on what strings are restricted.

Comment: For example, if I’m looking at $L=2$ and restrict “00”. Then, any distribution that satisfies $p(00)=0, p(01)\geq0.25,p(10)\geq0.25,p(11)\geq0.25$ fits the bill. You don’t specify what happens to the additional probability mass we end up with, in this case 0.25. Whichever way you re-distribute that, you’ll end up with a distribution that is element-wise greater than or equal to the non-restricted one and has a support of size $2^L - i$. These are all the conditions implied by your definition. You need to be more restrictive about what restriction means to get a unique joint probability.

Comment: Understood. Let's say this additional probability mass is redistributed equally among the remaining sequences.